I am not able to extract URL from these cell values using Google Apps Script
This is the link to the sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uNywYrkfptgy6muJe3ur_5AoB4eIOhhysf9Ljd9x5Ns/edit?gid=0#gid=0
[I have made using a new id so privacy is not an issue here].
Code:
function copyUrlsToColumnD() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Get the last row with data in the sheet
  
  for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange("B" + i);
    var richText = cell.getRichTextValue();
    
    if (richText) {
      var url = richText.getLinkUrl();
      if (url) {
        sheet.getRange("D" + i).setValue(url);
      } else {
        sheet.getRange("D" + i).setValue("No link found");
      }
    } else {
      sheet.getRange("D" + i).setValue("No rich text");
    }
  }
}

Issue:
If I single click cell B3 and then click on hyperlink icon in the menu and click apply on hyperlink pop-up and then run script, it gives URL. I have 100s of rows and I can't manually do this. I did in this cell B3 and so it gives output but other rows don't give me URLs.
I have 100s of rows and I can't manually do this.
I have spend several hours with many combinations and going through many questions but it has not worked for me. I don't understand the right syntax. I am a total beginner.
Can someone please give me a custom function to extract URLs from this cell.
I really need help. Pls help.

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that the URL is not set to the whole cell value. By this, richText.getLinkUrl() returns null. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function copyUrlsToColumnD() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B3:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getRichTextValues().map(([b]) => [[...new Set(b.getRuns().flatMap(r => r.getLinkUrl() || []))].join(",") || ""]);
  range.offset(0, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}

Testing:
When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

Reference:

getRuns()


Hi, thank you so much for this great help. I do not have words to express my gratitude. Thank you. You are so good in this.

@user18308583 About Hi, thank you so much for this great help. I do not have words to express my gratitude. Thank you. You are so good in this., welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

You're right. I thought I have already done that. I missed it. It is my mistake.

Hi. Do you have any tutorial/courses for absolute beginners by you in GAS? Pls help.

@user18308583 Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About Hi. Do you have any tutorial/courses for absolute beginners by you in GAS? Pls help., this page might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info
